# Nokogiri XML XPath does not select nodes in OpenXML Relationships file

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, openxml

I am trying to query the nodes of the following sample relationships XML file contained in the OpenXML presentationML format.

```
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <Relationship Target="../notesSlides/notesSlide1.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/notesSlide" Id="rId2"/>
    <Relationship Target="../slideLayouts/slideLayout2.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/slideLayout" Id="rId1"/>
    <Relationship Target="../media/image00.jpg" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Id="rId3"/>
</Relationships>
```

What I want is to select the attribute @Target for the Relationship node with Id="rId3". No matter what XPath selector I pass, the resulting nodeset is empty. Can anyone help solve this mystery?

Comment: What sort of selectors have you tried? You say "No matter what XPath selector I pass", but obviously you aren't doing them right, so show us what you tried so we can correct your work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very easy question, but because you're not showing your work I'm hesitant to simply hand you an answer.

Instead, here are some basic building blocks, not using XPath, which would work, but using CSS which will be a bit more readable:

The `at` method searches a document for the first occurrence of the selector. This uses a CSS selector to find the first `<Relationship>` nodes:

```
at('Relationship')
```

In CSS, you can find a particular node using its ID easily:

```
at('#rId3')
```

Using regular CSS rules, which are available all over the internet, you can combine those to find the node you want. It's essential to understand HTML and how CSS accesses nodes using selectors, but once you know that it makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

The mystery is that you're forgetting the namespace:

```
doc.at('//Relationship[@Id="rId3"]')[:Target]
```

fails because it looks for an element with no namespace

```
doc.at('//xmlns:Relationship[@Id="rId3"]')[:Target]
```

works